# Get post featured image id with $wpdb

Tags: post-thumbnails, mysql, wpdb

I'm not a sql expert, but with some help and copying from queries I've found on the web I got this working one that gets the 20 closest places (custom post type) to a specific latitude and longitude ($lat and $long). How can I edit this query to have also the post thumbnail ID in it? I want to do this to reduce the number of queries in my pages, so I think that looking for the value directly with this query instead of using get_post_thumbnail_id() each time I will save some, right?

```
SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->posts.post_title, $wpdb->terms.name,
    wpcflat.meta_value AS latitude, wpcflong.meta_value AS longitude, 
    6371 * 2 * ASIN ( SQRT (POWER(SIN(($lat - wpcflat.meta_value)*pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS($lat * pi()/180) * COS(wpcflat.meta_value *pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(($long - wpcflong.meta_value) *pi()/180 / 2), 2) ) ) AS distance
FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS wpcflong ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = wpcflong.post_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS wpcflat ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = wpcflat.post_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID NOT IN ($post->ID)
AND wpcflat.meta_key = 'wpcf-latitude'
AND wpcflong.meta_key = 'wpcf-longitude'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'places'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'countries'
ORDER BY DISTANCE
LIMIT 20
```

Thanks a lot in advance to everyone!

Comment: the post thumbnail id is stored in `$wpdb->postmeta` under column `meta_value` where `meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'` and post id is in column `post_id`. Maybe this will help you to write the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but this should work:

```
SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->posts.post_title, $wpdb->terms.name,
    wpcflat.meta_value AS latitude, wpcflong.meta_value AS longitude, 
    6371 * 2 * ASIN ( SQRT (POWER(SIN(($lat - wpcflat.meta_value)*pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS($lat * pi()/180) * COS(wpcflat.meta_value *pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(($long - wpcflong.meta_value) *pi()/180 / 2), 2) ) ) AS distance, wpcfthumbnail AS thumbnail_id;
FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS wpcflong ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = wpcflong.post_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS wpcflat ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = wpcflat.post_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS wpcfthumbnail ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = wpcfthumbnail.post_id)
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID NOT IN ($post->ID)
AND wpcflat.meta_key = 'wpcf-latitude'
AND wpcflong.meta_key = 'wpcf-longitude'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'places'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'countries'
AND wpcfthumbnail.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
ORDER BY DISTANCE
LIMIT 20
```

I added these bits of code:

```
, wpcfthumbnail AS thumbnail_id;
...
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS wpcfthumbnail ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = wpcfthumbnail.post_id)
...
AND wpcfthumbnail.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
```

Edit: This works.

```
SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->posts.post_title, $wpdb->terms.name, getthumbinfo.meta_value AS metainfo,
    thelat.meta_value AS latitude,thelong.meta_value AS longitude, 
    ASIN ( SQRT (POWER(SIN(($lat - thelat.meta_value)*pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS($lat * pi()/180) * COS(thelat.meta_value *pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(($long - thelong.meta_value) *pi()/180 / 2), 2) ) ) AS distance
FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS thelong ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = thelong.post_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS thelat ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = thelat.post_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS getthumbid ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = getthumbid.post_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS getthumbinfo ON (getthumbid.meta_value = getthumbinfo.post_id)
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID NOT IN ($post->ID)
    AND thelat.meta_key = 'wpcf-latitude'
    AND thelong.meta_key = 'wpcf-longitude'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'places'
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'countries'
    AND getthumbid.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
    AND getthumbinfo.meta_key = '_wp_attachment_metadata'
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 12
```

Comment: thank you, but nope, it's not working... I also did something similar following Mridul Aggarwal comment, but without success.

How can I see if there is a sql error in the query?

Comment: IT WORKS! There was just a small fix to do in the query... the first line of code you added should be "wpcfthumbnail.meta_value AS thumbnail_id" instead of "wpcfthumbnail AS thumbnail_id" ;) Here you can find the final working version of the query! Thanks!

Comment: @Stefano, right, glad it worked out :).

Comment: forgot a pastebin link to the final query version: http://pastebin.com/muaDNSRh